# Gravar saidas do bash linux, em um arquivo

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, time, txt

Preciso fazer alguns testes na linha de comando do linux, mas fazer todos os testes é muito demorado, alguém pode me ajudar, se tiver como, a escrever código em shell script para executar todos os testes, e gravar a saída do bash em um arquivo txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tudo o que você executa manualmente na shell é "código shell script". Portanto, crie um arquivo de script contendo a execução dos seus testes e o execute redirecionando sua saída para o arquivo desejado:

Arquivo *testes.sh*:

```
#/bin/bash

#script de teste...
echo "$(date '+%F %T') Executando teste1.sh";
./teste1.sh;
echo "$(date '+%F %T') teste1.sh finalizado";

#teste de trecho de codigo...
echo "$(date '+%F %T') Executando teste de for loop...";
for i in {1..100}; do
   echo $i;
done;
echo "$(date '+%F %T') for loop finalizado";

#teste de execucao de ferramenta de sistema...
echo "$(date '+%F %T') Efetuando coletas de vmstat";
vmstat 1 3;
echo "$(date '+%F %T') vmstat coletado";
```

No exemplo acima incluí mensagens informativas com a data e hora de início e término da execução de cada passo. Os passos são hipotéticos, você pode incluir os comandos que quiser, lembrando que a princípio o `teste1.sh` não existe, e foi só incluído como exemplo de execução de script arbitrário.

Não se esqueça também de marcar seu script como executável:

```
chmod +x testes.sh;
```

Ao executar *testes.sh*, redirecione sua saída para seu arquivo de log, tanto a saída padrão quanto a de erro, para garantir que terá todas as informações sobre os comandos executados:

```
./testes.sh >> saida.txt 2>&1
```

Isso funciona porque todos os comandos encapsulados em *testes.sh* estão direcionados para a saída padrão, aí você só precisa redirecionar a saída de *testes.sh* para onde achar melhor. Sendo assim, certifique-se de que não está redirecionando sem querer a saída de testes individuais para outros arquivos.